# PHP bytearray to binary data

Tags: php, encryption, binary, pack, unpack

I have:

```
$my_a = array(100, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Which is a byte-array which I want to convert to binary data to use with encryption. What I do is:

```
$bin_data         = pack("C*", $my_a);
```

To validate if this is correct I reverse it by:

```
unpack("C*", $bin_data);
```

Problem is, I never get back the byte_array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pack()` can't take a single array argument, unfortunately. You need to unpack the array into additional arguments.

Use the splat operator if you're using PHP 5.6+

```
$packed = pack('C*', ...$my_a);
```

From the manual: Arrays and Traversable objects can be unpacked into argument lists when calling functions by using the ... operator. This is also known as the splat operator in other languages, including Ruby.

So the array is unpacked into single arguments, just like it is needed by `pack()`.

---

#### Before PHP 5.6

You can use the following instead:

```
$packed = call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), $my_a));
```

This will basically merge the packing argument with your data array and the function `call_user_func_array()` will call `pack()` with all arguments extracted from the given array, as single arguments, like needed.

Comment: Damn, i searched for this answer for hours now................. *annoying* To proud to ask I think. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can't send array to pack. Do it right with `splat` operator `$bin_data = pack("C*", ...$my_a);`

About `splat` `...`: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat